# ¿Como validar un registro en un trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Para evitar hacer la validación por código quisiera que dentro de mysql al momento de insertar el detalle de un préstamo crear un `trigger` para validar si la `cantidad de artículos` en la `tabla artículos` **es mayor a cero**, que me deje actualizar la tabla articulos en caso contrario no actualizar.

Esto es lo que realizado por el momento en phpmyadmin.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ACTUALIZAP_BI;
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER ACTUALIZAP_BI BEFORE INSERT ON detalleprestamo FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE V = @SELECT cant_articulo FROM articulos WHERE id_articulo = new.idarticulo;
        IF V > 0 THEN
            DECLARE T = UPDATE articulos SET
            cant_articulo = (cant_articulo - new.unidades) WHERE id_articulo = new.idarticulo;
        ELSE 
            DECLARE T = FALSE;
        END IF;
        SELECT T;
END;
DELIMITER $$;
```

Comment: "No ha funcionado" es muy vago. Que error te sale al usarlo?

Comment: no tira errores, no me crear el trigger, puede que este mal la sentencia, pero el gestor no me indica en donde o porque.

Comment: Para esta y otras preguntas, suele ser útil indicar si estás usando phpmyadmin o alguna otra herramienta para correr tu código. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hay una mezcla incorrecta de delimitadores en el código. Además, intentas hacer un SELECT que no es válido en el trigger (no te va a retornar el resultado)

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ACTUALIZAP_BI;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ACTUALIZAP_BI BEFORE INSERT ON detalleprestamo FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_cant_articulos int(11);

    SELECT cant_articulo INTO v_cant_articulos FROM articulos WHERE id_articulo = new.idarticulo;
    IF v_cant_articulos > 0 THEN
       UPDATE articulos SET cant_articulo = (cant_articulo - new.unidades) WHERE id_articulo = new.idarticulo;
    END IF;
    -- SELECT T; //No puedes hacer SELECT en el trigger esperando que lo retorne
END $$ -- Cambiaste el delimitador, úsalo!
DELIMITER ;  -- Y así es que se regresa al delimitador habitual
```

Comment: Hola alfabravo gracias por tu disposicion, he intentado copiar y pegar tu codigo pero tengo el siguiente error:::
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '= @SELECT cant_articulo FROM articulos WHERE id_articulo = new.idarticulo;
    ' en la linea 3

Comment: Perdón, no corregí la declaración de la variable. un SELECT INTO debería funcionar. Ya modifiqué el código, espero sea útil.